# Why are mango leaves kept in the kalash during puja ritual?

Tags: puja

I have seen that mango leaves kept in the kalash during puja ritual. Why are mango leaves kept in the kalash during puja ritual?

Answer (score 1):

> The Kalash is used for creating seat for invoked deities during the
>   puja ritual. First it is filled with water and then  leaves of mango
>   tree or that of betel vine are kept in it. These leaves are known as
>   leaves of deity’s seat. The deity principle gets maximally attracted
>   to these leaves of seat. The water inside the Kalash keeps this seat
>   pure till the ritual of Pranapratishta (invoking deity into an image,
>   idol, coconut or betelnut). Thus the invoked deity principle stays for
>   a long period.
>
> In this Kalash betel nut or some coins are then put. Thereafter a
>   coconut is set up on the mouth of the Kalash. The tuft of coconut
>   attracts the deity principle from the atmosphere and it is then
>   transmitted to the water in the Kalash through the body of coconut.
>
> The water is pure and clean to the highest extent. That is the reason
>   it is able to attract the sattvik particles of frequencies of deities.
>   But it contains less quantity of raja particles and therefore has poor
>   capacity to project the sattva particles.
>
> Putting a coin is symbol of sacrifice. Through this medium there is
>   sacrifice of wealth and jiva (embodied soul)’s attachment is reduced.
>   This qualifies the worshipper to benefit more from the sattvikta of
>   puja ritual. A copper coin is put in the kalash. The copper has more
>   capacity to project sattvik frequencies. It helps in emanation of
>   sattvik frequencies present in the water into the atmosphere.
>
> Also a betel nut is kept in the kalash meant for puja ritual. Betelnut
>   enhances sattva and raja components in the water of the kalash. This
>   increases the capacity of the water to emit manifest principle of
>   deity.The betel nut contains particles related to absolute earth
>   element which are useful in binding of sattva particles related to
>   sattva component.This then easily helps in retaining the sattvikta of
>   water for along time. Five  precious stones like pearl, diamond,
>   emerald, blue sapphire, ruby and gold are also added to the water of
>   Kalash. The five precious stones and gold have capacity to attract and
>   emit the principles of five superior deities. This  benefits the
>   worshiper. But with changing times the use of five precious stones and
>   copper is reduced and replaced by alloys which are spiritually of less
>   benefit.
>
> Now let us see as to why the water stored in the Kalash is either
>   poured under the Tulsi plant or is sprinkled in the premises after the
>   conclusion of puja.

[For Detail you can check Why are mango leaves kept in the kalash during puja ritual?](https://www.hindujagruti.org/hinduism/knowledge/article/why-are-mango-leaves-kept-in-the-kalash-during-puja-ritual.html#41)

Comment: You copied content from [this site](https://www.hindujagruti.org/hinduism/knowledge/article/why-are-mango-leaves-kept-in-the-kalash-during-puja-ritual.html) but didn't cite any source. Plagiarism is not allowed on SE sites.

Answer (score 1):

> Kalasha is a brass, mud, or copper pot filled with water or rice.
>   Mango leaves are kept on the pot and a coconut is placed over it. In
>   some areas, a red cloth or green cloth is covered around the coconut.
>   Some threads are also tied around the pot. Devotees decorate the pot
>   with kumkum (vermillion), haldi, and some other decorative items. Such
>   pot is referred to as Kalasha.
>
> Kalasha Puja is the most popular and revered ritual during
>   grihapravesh (house warming ceremony), vivah (marriage / wedding),
>   Navratri Durga Puja, Diwali Lakshmi Puja, and in temple festivals like
>   Kumbhabhishekam, Brahmotsavam, etc.
>
> Why do we worship Kalasha? The water in the kalasha represents the
>   primordial water from which the entire creation emerged. Water is the
>   giver of life and the source of all forms and objects of the creation.
>   The mango leaves symbolize the creation. The threads signify the love
>   and peace that bins everything in creation
>
> We worship Gods and Goddesses, and love our parents, brothers,
>   sisters, wife, children, relatives, friends, and well wishers, but we
>   would not worship the creation and the universe from which we are
>   emerged and in which we are living. To accomplish the worship of
>   everything in our universe, Kalasha Sthapana puja and Kalasha Puja is
>   performed during any puja.

[Source](http://hindupad.com/kalasha-puja-purpose-why-do-we-worship-the-kalasha/)

**Kalasha Sthapana Vidhi**

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Sve7ZOn7p68

**Significance of using mango leaves in Pujas:**

- Symbol of Mahalakshmi
- Prevents negative energy
- Sign of Auspiciousness
- Helps against drushti dosham
- Full of Oxygen
- Promotes hygiene and health
- Symbol of fertility